# In Scala/Java, how to inspect where a method is defined?

Tags: java, scala, reflection, inspect

For example, I saw a Scala expression like this:

```
objX.methodY
```

There seems no way to see where `methodY` came from, it may came from:

(1) the class of `objX`, let's call it `ClassX`

(2) the super class of `objX` (`ClassX`), let's call it `SuperClassX`

(3) a class called `ClassZ`, `ClassZ` is irrelevant to `objX`, but there is an implicit conversion from `ClassX` to `ClassZ`.

So there may be three possibilities for the source of `methodY`, does anyone have ideas about how to find out where the `methodY` is defined?

In other words, in Scala, how to inspect the information of a method (especially the method came from **implicit conversion**) at Runtime?

Comment: I don't know about scala; but in Java, you can think this way - the method is always "on" the runtime class of the object; if that class does not define the method, it "inherits" the definition of the method from the super class.

Comment: @bayou.io Yes, and Scala introduced the `implicit conversion`, which makes the searching more difficult..

Comment: I suspect that implicit conversion is resolved at compile time, not runtime. - but again I don't know scala.

Comment: The implicit is resolved at compile time, but hard to say from where it comes w/o trying to remove `import` one by one. That's why I would not use implicit conversion to pimp.

Answer (score 0):

There is the possibility to get Class which has the method declared by reflection. With your namings:

```
objX.getClass().getMethod("methodY").getDeclaringClass();
```

Comment: You are using Java reflection, Java reflection doesn't know anything about Scala semantics. You'll probably have to use Scala reflection.

Answer (score 0):

At runtime the code would be replaced with something like `convertToY(objX).methodY`, so at that point there's no connection to objX to inspect, it's just a function parameter. What are you trying to accomplish?